# Selecting multiple columns in dplyr, then mutating those observations in those columns to NA if they match a value?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-management

I have a data frame whose columns I want to retain as is, but mutate nonsensical values (*i.e. daily calorie intake = 88888*) to NA. I am trying to do this with **dplyr**, but cannot find a solution which combines the column names as a list or that match a prefix (all start with "DRPN"), and change the 88888 values to NA.

Tried `mutate_if()` but the function will not take the list of columns.

Tried `mutate_at()` but the function doesn't accept my requirements.

```
df_recode <- lab1_final %>%
          select(vars(starts_with("DRPN")) %>%
          mutate_if(vars, "88888", NA)
```

Which I am trying to get to swap the 88888 observations with NA so that I can properly analyze the continuous variables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here, we can use `mutate_at` instead of `mutate_if`.  Also, if the intention is to mutate only selected columns, then we don't need the `select` before

```
library(dplyr)
lab1_final %>%
      mutate_at(vars(starts_with("DRPN")), na_if, y = "88888")
```

---

However, if we are interested in only `select` a subset of columns and return only those, use `trasmute_at` (this can avoid one step - or `select` with `mutate_all`)

```
lab1_final %>%
      transmute_at(vars(starts_with("DRPN")), na_if, y = "88888")
```

The quote is not needed `88888` if there are numeric columns.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why that was so troubling.